# Parsing a big text file and extract data without looping more than once - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, logging, big-o

I want to parse a large text log file (around 1M lines). Example below:

> 2016-11-08 03:49.879 alfa: (157) all is good
>
> 2016-11-08 03:49.979 alfa: (157) there is an **ERROR** here
>
> 2016-11-08 03:50.879 gamma: (2) something else is here
>
> 2016-11-08 03:51.879 delta: (69) something is going on

What I want to achieve is look for errors and then return all lines related to that error - alfa in this case. The problem is when I loop the first time and find error, then save alfa (157) as reference, how do I then return all alfa (157) lines (even those which happend before the error like in example) without looping through the 1M lines again. What if there are 50 errors? Is this possible? Is it an O(n2) problem?

I wanted to use Python:

```
def analyze_log(f):
    for line in f:
        (..)
```

Comment: Group errors in a `dict` where the keys are the log label and the values are lists of lines. Than you can use that dict to print the report.

Comment: Are all the lines that you want to grab consecutive?

Comment: @jure they are until (number), messages are of different length

Answer (score 1):

1M lines is not that big for modern hardware, I would assemble an in-memory database using a dict. Something like:

```
log_database = {}
for i, line in enumerate(logfile):
    date, time, label, message = line.split(None, 3)
    log_database.setdefault(label, []).append({
        "line number": i,
        "date": date,
        "time": time,
        "message": message,
    })
```

Comment: would I have to handle the in-memory database after running the script? Will it delete itself from memory or do I have to handle it?

Comment: If you want access to the data after the script runs you will have to persist it someway, for example, dumping it to a JSON file (or just use a relational database like `sqlite` or `mysql`). All memory is reclaimed after the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you build a pipeline, that way you can perform multiple operations on every line. If you want to get fancier you could even build it using coroutines and then run in parallel asynchronously.

```
def has_errors(line):
    return True if ('alfa' in line and 'ERROR' in line) else False

def do_something(line):
    # add your processing logic
    processed = line
    return processed

errors = list()
processed = list()

with open('kwyjibo.log') as log_file:
    for line in log_file:
        if has_errors(line):
            errors.append(line)
        processed.append(do_something(line))

# contents of kwyjibo.log
# 2016-11-08 03:49.879 alfa: (157) all is good
# 2016-11-08 03:49.979 alfa: (157) there is an ERROR here
# 2016-11-08 03:50.879 gamma: (2) something else is here
# 2016-11-08 03:51.879 delta: (69) something is going on

# Output
# In [3]: errors
# Out[3]: ['2016-11-08 03:49.979 alfa: (157) there is an ERROR here\n']

# In [4]: processed
# Out[4]:
# ['2016-11-08 03:49.879 alfa: (157) all is good\n',
# '2016-11-08 03:49.979 alfa: (157) there is an ERROR here\n',
# '2016-11-08 03:50.879 gamma: (2) something else is here\n',
# '2016-11-08 03:51.879 delta: (69) something is going on\n']
```

Comment: The benefit of this approach is that you can have as many different processing steps as you want. Think of using *NIX type tools where you build pipelines. The great thing about this approach is that if you make it concurrent by making the processing elements coroutines and then making the execution parallel you can scale horizontally.

Comment: did you try this approach on big files? couple million lines?

Comment: @Always_hungry I've used this approach with files of 4 million lines. If you have issues with memory, constraints then you'll need to consider how you handle the output of each processing step, maybe rather than store it in a list your write it to another file. In cases like this I usually, write my application so can run concurrently and then I run it in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You could append all lines from error 157, or any orher error, in the same dict key:

```
log_errors = {}
...
if log_errors.has_key(error_key):
    log_errors[error_key].append(line_from_log)
else:
    log_errors[error_key] = line_from_log
```

PS. has_key() has been removed from python 3, use 'in' operator instead.